# How to do aggregation on dataframe to get distinct count of column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I apply where condition on dataframe ,example I need to groupBy on one column and count the distinct values in the column based on certain where condition.I need to do this where condition for multiple columns

I tried the below way.Please let me know how Can I do this.

```
case class testRdd(name:String,id:Int,price:Int)
val Cols = testRdd.toDF().groupBy("id").agg( countDistinct("name").when(col("price")>0,1).otherwise(0)
```

This will not work,or Is there a way to do something like ? Thanks in advance

```
testRdd.toDF().groupBy("id").agg(if(col("price")>0)countDistinct("name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testRDD.select("name","id").where($"price">0).distinct.groupBy($"id").agg( count("name")).show
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach to @Robin's answer, namely introducing an additional boolean column to group

```
df.groupBy($"id",when($"price">0,true).otherwise(false).as("positive_price"))
.agg(
  countDistinct($"name")
)
.where($"positive_price")
.show
```

Comment: I have multiple columns to apply where condition on, for 1 column I can do this but I can't add more columns there,is there a way to apply on multiple columns